# delete an order once it is converted back to a quote in EE 1.14.0.1

Tags: magento-enterprise, sales-quote, conversion

I have a Magento EE 1.14.0.1 and am working on a custom paypal type payment processor.

I have it all working with the exception of if once a customer gets to the external payment processors page and clicks the cancel button I have code that will when they come back to the site convert their order to a quote and direct them to their view cart page. However the order is still staying listed in the sales order page as "pending. However I want to have it removed from the sales order listing page since it has been converted back to a quote and is no longer an order.

below is the code I am using to take the order and convert it back to a quote 
I am not sure what to add or alter.

```
   $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($order->getQuoteId());
        if ($quote->getId()) {
                                $quote->setIsActive(1)
                                    //->setReservedOrderId(null)
                                      ->save();

                                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')
                                           ->replaceQuote($quote);
                                        // ->unsLastRealOrderId();
                                                }
                                $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
                             }
```

What I want is after the order is converted to a quote to DELETE the order from being listed in the sales order page not just have it listed as cancelled.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function cancelAction()
{
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
    if ($session->getLastRealOrderId())
    {
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($session->getLastRealOrderId());
        if ($order->getId())
        {
            //Cancel order
            if ($order->getState() != Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED)
            {
                $order->registerCancellation("Canceled by Payment Provider")->save();
            }
            $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
                ->load($order->getQuoteId());
            //Return quote
            if ($quote->getId())
            {
                $quote->setIsActive(1)
                    ->setReservedOrderId(NULL)
                    ->save();
                $session->replaceQuote($quote);
            }

            //Unset data
            $session->unsLastRealOrderId();
        }
    }

    return $this->getResponse()->setRedirect( Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart'));
}
```